# How to get values from dynamically generated page and its form fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building an android application using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile.

I am having problem fetching the values of form fields in jQuery of a dynamically generated page (data-role="page") which contains the form and fields.

My code is like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $page('<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="editKeeperForm">
    <div data-role="content">
     <form method="POST" action="editKeeper" data-ajax="false">
      <input type="text" name="name2" id="name"  data-clear-btn="true" 
 value='+keeperRecord.fld_keeperName+'>
      <input type="submit" id="save" value="Save">
     </form>
    </div>
    </div>');
    $page.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
    $page.page();
    $.mobile.changePage( $page );

    $(document).on('click', '#editKeeperForm #save', function () {
     console.log($("#name").val());
    });
    </script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but, "My code is something like this". Is the the Script you are Using? or something like the script you are using. Without knowing what you are doing exactly, one can not know how to help you

Comment: I just reduced the form, since it is too big. Other than that it's the same. @Tasos

Comment: @SohaibAhmed Could you put your code in jsfiddle I can help you with this issue

Comment: I just made an account there, and I shall try. Meanwhile I tried using `console.log($("#name"))` which shows all the attributes except value. However when I use `console.log($(this))` it does show value attribute of input field and it's correct content. @Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to work around this problem
$(this).find("#name").val();

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
$("#save").click(function () {
      console.log($("#name").val());
});
```

Do you get the same issue?

Since this is a dynamically generated page you may have to use

```
$("#editKeeperForm").enhanceWithin()
```

after you generate it. This is often the case with dynamically generated things in jQuery Mobile.

Comment: For some eldritch reason `$("#save").click(function(){` is not triggering. Please, where should I use `enhanceWithin` before `pagechange` or after?
Upon using `console.log($("#name"))`, shows  all the attributes except `value`. However when I use `console.log($(this))` it does show value attribute of input field and it's correct content. @SubjectiveEffect

Comment: You use enhanceWithin AFTER the rest of the page is built, so at the end of all the other code (or when all the other code has finished its job). Think of it as a page refresh.